# Flutter - How to send click event on a transparent area of an image to the next level?

Tags: flutter

I'm a newer in flutter. Now I have a problem.

[image]

I want click the transparent area and send the click event to the bottom layer, click non-transparent area and self layer can responce event.

I think hittest method can solve.

Thx~~

codes below:

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: InkButton(
              onTap: () {
                print('aaa');
              },
              child: Image.asset(
                'lib/bg_bottom.png',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            left: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            child: InkButton(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Image.asset(
                'lib/bg_top.png',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img_lib;

class TransparentIgnorePointer extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final img_lib.Image image;
  final Size transformSize;
  final int index;

  const TransparentIgnorePointer({
    Key? key,
    required Widget child,
    required this.image,
    required this.transformSize,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, covariant TransparentRenderIgnorePointer renderObject) {
    renderObject.image = image;
    renderObject.transformSize = transformSize;
    renderObject.index = index;
  }

  @override
  TransparentRenderIgnorePointer createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return TransparentRenderIgnorePointer(
      image: image,
      transformSize: transformSize,
      index: index,
    );
  }
}

class TransparentRenderIgnorePointer extends RenderProxyBox {
  img_lib.Image image;
  Size transformSize;
  int index;

  TransparentRenderIgnorePointer({
    required this.image,
    required this.transformSize,
    required this.index,
  });

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    return _hitUnIgnores(position) && super.hitTest(result, position: position);
  }

  bool _hitUnIgnores(Offset offset) {
    final pixelX = (offset.dx / transformSize.width * image.width).round();
    final pixelY = (offset.dy / transformSize.height * image.height).round();
    if (pixelX < 0 ||
        pixelY < 0 ||
        pixelX >= image.width ||
        pixelY >= image.height) {
      return false;
    }
    final pixel = image.getPixel(pixelX, pixelY);
    final result = pixel.a != 0;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`GestureDetector` with `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque` should do the trick.

```dart
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onTap: () {},
  child: Image.asset(...),
)
```